# Ionic 2 Save and Retrieve Shopping Cart item LocalStorage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

i've create an `ionic 2 application` with **shopping cart feature**, but my **problem** when i `save the item in the cart` and go to **other page** and open `the cart` in this case the cart is **empty**

**My Question:**

**How can i create a shopping cart functionality and retrieve in another page from my code below ?**

here is my code :

**user-data.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Events, LocalStorage, Storage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  _cart = [];
  HAS_LOGGED_IN = 'hasLoggedIn';
  storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);

  constructor(public events: Events) {}

  hasItem(item) {
    return (this._cart.indexOf(item) > -1);
  }

  addToCart(item) {
    this._cart.push(item);
  }

  removeFromCart(item) {
    let index = this._cart.indexOf(item);
    //item.checked=false;
    if (index > -1) {
      this._cart.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  clearCart(){
    this._cart = [];
  }

  indexOfItem(item) {
    return this._cart.indexOf(item);
  }

  countOfCart() {
    return this._cart.length;
  }

  login(name) {
    this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
    this.setUsername(name);
    this.events.publish('user:login');
  }

  signup() {
    this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
    this.events.publish('user:signup');
  }

  logout() {
    this.storage.remove(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN);
    this.storage.remove('username');
    this.events.publish('user:logout');
  }

  setUsername(username) {
    this.storage.set('username', username);
  }
  getUsername() {
    return this.storage.get('username').then((value) => {
      return value;
    });
  }

  // return a promise
  hasLoggedIn() {
    return this.storage.get(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN).then((value) => {
      return value;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be right, but in order to use the **same instance of the `UserData` class, you should include it in the providers array of the top-most component where they must be shared**.

What does this mean? Well, if you include the `UserData` class in the providers array of the Page1, a new instance of that class will be injected in your page. The problem is that if you also include it in your providers array of your Page2, a new (and different) instance of the `UserClass` will be injected in that page too. So the instance where you add things to your cart in the Page1, will be different of the instance that you use to read the content of your cart in the Page2. That's why it seems to be *empty*.

If you want to be able to use the same instance of the class in the entire app, you should include it in the top-most component of the app:

```
@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [UserData]
})
```

By doing that, the same *instance* of the class will be used in the entire application.

Comment: Yeh that's right 100% , thanks for your response :).

Comment: Glad I could help :)